# Replace manual input from terminal with file or text input in bash

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to pass password via pipe or file as input to a bash script which expects input from command line therefore I get  the following error:
 "could not get password from environment or keystore and stdin not a tty". Is there some way I can replace the stdin with file or text input?

Comment: You might be able to do that with `expect`.

Comment: Which application is requesting the password? Is it ssh?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use "expect" to pass text to a pgm that is reading from a non-tty.

This page might be useful for you:  https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/

Answer (score 0):

**Expect program for expecting password**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn su $1
expect "Password:" #expects the keyword "Password:"
send "$2\r";

interact
```

**Output when you run the above program**

```
smilyface@localhost $ ./su.exp guest guest
spawn su guest
Password:
guest@localhost $
```